# Is there a way to set a list value in a range of integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to perform the following:

```
>>> [0-2, 4]  #case 1
[-2, 4]     #I want the output to be [0, 1, 2, 4]
```

I know I can perform the same in this way:

```
>>> list(range(3)) + [4]   #case 2
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

But I am curious is there any way to achieve the same result using the case 1 method (or something similar)? Do I need to override the integer '-' operator or do I need to do anything with the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> [*range(0,3), 4]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Should come closest. Python 3 only.

Comment: And now you have a list of ranges and static values. Go!

Comment: @user1767754 I refuse. The fact that we can't use starred expressions in list comprehensions make this case boring.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, because I tried [range(0,3), 4] and it returns the functions as index 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [`@timgeb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539335/7434365) is great, but this returns a `list`, and by default range returns an `"an immutable sequence type"` and so using `itertools.chain` would give an `iterable` that is more closely related to `range()`.

```
import itertools
itertools.chain(range(3), range(4,5))
```

which (once converting to a `list` with `list()` so we can see the contents) would give:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

---

Or you could make your own `generator`:

```
def joinRanges(r1, r2):
    for i in r1:
        yield i
    for i in r2:
        yield i
```

which achieves the same effect as before when calling with:

```
joinRanges(range(3), range(4,5))
```